# How to import csv which have lines that are ends with separate character?

Tags: mysql, import

> **11110|2005001|abc|apple|00|good|fine|2|||||0|||go|stop||20100520|**

Above is an example of csv data.

I'm trying to import a csv into database table.

But every time I try, it has fail with this error message : Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.

Every line of the csv ends with separate character '|'.

I think that is why keep failing to import data.

I chose options like this :

```
partial import :                 uncheck;
format of imported file :        csv
option - fields terminated by :  |
option - fields enclosed by by :
option - field escaped by :      \
option - lines terminated by :   auto
option - column names :
```

How can I import these csv files into db?

Can not delete the '|' at the end of the line.

Because there are more than 400,000 lines in csv file.

And I don't know regular expression and some of lines are ends with '|||' like this;;

> **11110|2005001|abc|apple|00|good|fine|2|||||0|||go|stop|||**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must transform your csv (make a backup before):

In a simple text editor remplace : ||||| by |
Then : |||| by |
...

At this point all your lines are ends with only one |

Just remplace | by , and save your file.

You can import the text file in mysql.